# Different notification url in Orion subscription rule with the same Cygnus instance

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

Is it possible to make several subscription of Orion just changing the notification url of cygnus using the same instance of Cygnus?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... Do you mean to use the same Cygnus instance listening in different port, each one associated to a different sink? Could you edit your question post to elaborate on the use case, please?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the official documentation of [Orion context broker](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/walkthrough_apiv2/index.html#subscriptions)

**The URL where to send notifications is defined with the url sub-field. Here we are using the URL of the accumulator-server.py program, previously started. Only one URL can be included per subscription. However, you can have several subscriptions on the same context elements (i.e. same entity and attribute) without any problem.**